# Updating all components using flatlist

Tags: react-native, react-redux, components

I am using a pattern in which 4 components use the same item. I made a different list likes QuotesList component, VideoList component, 'AllList component'. All of these uses `FlatList` which goes to Item component.
Suppose my AllList contain data which is in QuotesList also. So how to manage so that if I make a change in any AllList also reflects the QuotesList.

## Flatlist for All tweets

```
<FlatList
            refreshing={this.state.refresh}
            onRefresh={()=>this.refreshAllTweets()}
            data={tweets}
            extraData={this.state.refreshFlatlist}
            keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
            renderItem={({item}) => <TweetItem reloadComponent={()=>this.reload()} name={this.state.name}  onPress={()=>this.goToDetail(item.id)} onImagePress={()=>this.toggleModal(item.id)} onCommentPress={()=>this.showComments(item.id)} tweet={item}/>}
            />
```

## Flatlist for Quotes tweets

```
<FlatList
            refreshing={this.state.refresh}
            onRefresh={()=>this.refreshQuotesTweets()}
            data={tweets}
            extraData={this.state.refreshFlatlist}
            ref={(c) => {this.flatList = c;}}
            keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
            renderItem={({item}) => <TweetItem reloadComponent={()=>this.reload()} name={this.state.name} onImagePress={()=>this.toggleModal(item.id)} onPress={()=>this.goToDetail(item.id)} onCommentPress={()=>this.showComments(item.id)} tweet={item}/>}
            />
```

I want that if I make any changes in a comment in all tweets component it must be reflected quotes tweet list. I even try with extra data but it is not working.

Comment: can you pls add some code too ? it is hard for us to help you without source code..

Comment: from no snippet I can suggest adding `<FlatList extraData={} ...> ...</FlatList>`. In `extraData` put some data so when that does change the list updates. We for an example have a redux subscriber param: `<FlatList extraData={this.props.subscriber} ...>...</FlatList>`. When this changes, all items in `FlatList` are re-rendered.

Comment: After reading it couple of times your question, try putting these data into redux store and subscribe components displaying these data to store. When ever you chance something in the store data, then the changes are reflected to subscribers. This is more optimal than previous comment as previous re-renders all items and this only the affected item.

Comment: @parohy I tried but it didn't worked

Comment: I also tried the thing with redux but nothing happening